# How to fix code examples in Python documentation?

Tags: python, formatting, documentation, code

I'm having a strange problem when trying to view the Python documentation. Basically, all code examples cut off the last line of text. The screenshot below illustrates what I mean. The text box isn't large enough to show the definition for "type". There is no way to scroll that text box down or to expand it, so its impossible for me to read that line.

How do I fix this? Is there any way I can read that last line? It happens on *all* of the multiline code examples in the docs and is very annoying. I'm on Windows XP, using the Python 2.7 docs.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

EDIT:

Thanks to martineau's answer below, I managed to figure out exactly what's happening. The horizontal scroll bar is obscuring the last line of text. By decreasing the font size (via both the 'Font' and 'Accessibility' settings martineau mentioned), the lines can be made to fit completely within the text box, thereby preventing the horizontal scroll bar from appearing.

Whose bright idea was it to make the scroll bar obscure the last line in a textbox?

[image: Screenshot from Python documentation]

Comment: Do you heavily use the index functions? If not maybe you could just [export the CHM to HTML](http://www.gridinsoft.com/chm.php) and open them in your default browser over the embedded IE

Comment: Actually, I use 'index' almost exclusively. Most of the time I need the docs, it's to lookup information on particular functions (in this case, I searched for 'format'). I would really hate to give that up.

Comment: I see, sorry I can't help you further besides suggesting changing font and window width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I, too, use Windows XP and encountered the same problem, which was very irritating since I tend to use Python's Help file a lot. After a lot of fiddling around and experimenting I was able to fix it up and it now looks like this:

[image: screenshot of Python Help window display]

This was accomplished by adjusting two of the settings under the Options / Internet Options... menu item. The first was to change the "Plain Text font" to something I like better (and use in my editor for writing code) by clicking on the Fonts button to bring up the Fonts dialog, as illustrated below:

[image: screenshot of fonts dialog]

To address the size issue, the second thing I did was to enable "Ignore font sizes specified on webpages" option in the Accessibility dialog which appears if when you click on the Accessibility button:

[image: screenshot of accessibility dialog]

Making these two changes also affects how things look in Internet Explorer, although not too badly, and besides I don't really care that much because I hardly ever use it -- your mileage may differ.

Last but not least, you have to make sure you have the window's width set wide enough to prevent scroll-bars appearing next to the the blocks of code

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, it's not just you (on XP). I get the same thing under Vista.

Try this for a workaround: Click at the beginning of the code sample and drag down until you've selected all of the code and the first letter of the sentence following the code box (see screenshot below). Then, keeping the mouse button down, slide left until that final letter is no longer selected. You now have the entire code sample selected. Hit `[Ctrl+C]` to copy and then paste into Notepad (or similar).

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea! Thank you. Hopefully the Python team will fix this properly.